# How can I bind a row so I can set isVisible to false in .cs file?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

It seems that I can't access it even if I put a name on it because it's inside a listview.  If i wan row1 to not be visible on code behind how do i go around this?

I tried to a name for Label but I can't access it. or added  I cant access on code behind.

```
<ListView x:Name="postListView" SeparatorVisibility="Default" HasUnevenRows="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SeparatorColor="White">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Grid BackgroundColor="Black" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                      VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="1,2,1,0">
                <Grid HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                      VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" ColumnSpacing="1" RowSpacing="1">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions >
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Label Grid.Row="0" FontSize="Medium" Grid.Column="0" Text="right tst:" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" BackgroundColor="cornflowerblue" />
                    <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding drain1vol}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" BackgroundColor="cornflowerblue"/>
                    <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="nothing"  BackgroundColor="Yellow"/>
                    <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding drain2vol}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" BackgroundColor="Yellow" />
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>

//Model and Source of data
using System;
using SQLite;
using Demo.Helpers;

namespace Demo.Model

{

//this is the source of Binding
public class Post
{

    //ID primary key that we will autoincrement   
    //These are binding source for Historypage
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public bool showLabel { get; set; }  //public class model
}
}
```

The source is the Post class.

Comment: this is an exact quote from a response to one of your other questions: "you can't access elements inside of a template from the code behind. Use databinding to set properties of template elements."

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/data-and-databinding#data-binding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binding the label's `IsVisible` property to the property in your model to control the visiable ability of the label.

For example,
In `xaml`:

```
 <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" IsVisible="{Binding showLabel}" Text="{Binding drain1vol}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" BackgroundColor="cornflowerblue"/>
```

And then in your `model`:

```
public class model
{
    public string drain1vol { get; set; }

    public bool showLabel { get; set; }

}
```

When you create the dataSource, you can set the label's `isVisable`:

```
    Items.Add(new model { drain1vol = "Rob Finnerty" ,showLabel= false });
    Items.Add(new model { drain1vol = "Bill Wrestler", showLabel = true });
    Items.Add(new model { drain1vol = "Dr. Geri-Beth Hooper", showLabel = false });
    Items.Add(new model { drain1vol = "Dr. Keith Joyce-Purdy", showLabel = true });
    Items.Add(new model { drain1vol = "Sheri Spruce", showLabel = false });

    postListView.ItemsSource = Items;
```

To change the `visiable` ability in code behind:

```
void test() {

    //Get the model you want to change
    model.showLabel = false / true;
}
```

**Update:**

Implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface in your model:

```
class model : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool showLabel { get; set; }

    private string drain1vol { get; set; }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;



    public bool ShowLabel
    {
        set
        {
            if (showLabel != value)
            {
                showLabel = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ShowLabel");     
            }
        }
        get
        {
            return showLabel;
        }
    }

    public string Drain1vol
    {
        set
        {
            if (drain1vol != value)
            {
                drain1vol = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Drain1vol");
            }
        }
        get
        {
            return drain1vol;
        }
    }
}
```

And in your xaml, binding to `ShowLabel` and `Drain1vol`(upper-case):

```
 <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" IsVisible="{Binding ShowLabel}" Text="{Binding Drain1vol}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" BackgroundColor="cornflowerblue"/>
```

Comment: Instead of accessing the Label is there a way to access the row? You know like <Grid grid.row name:"gridrow1" />  then on code behind gridrow1.isVisible = false;

Comment: It's still visible?                 <!-- rain1 Row 1 odd rows are conrflowerblue-->
                <Label Grid.Row="1" FontSize="Medium" Grid.Column="0" IsVisible="{Binding showLabel}" Text="{Binding rain1Lbl}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"  />               
                <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding rain1vol}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" /> 
                                <!-- endrow1   -->   and in code behind Post.showLabel = false;

Comment: @hypnocool If you want to hide a row, set the rowHeight = 0 to achieve that. Check these threads: [how-to-hide-a-grid-row-and-listview-column-so-that-no-empty-space-is-visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50894343/how-to-hide-a-grid-row-and-listview-column-so-that-no-empty-space-is-visible?rq=1) and [how-to-hide-a-row-or-column-in-a-grid-layout](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/17552/how-to-hide-a-row-or-column-in-a-grid-layout)

Comment: on the code behind on the update am I supposed to use lowercase    model.showLabel = false / true; or    model.ShowLabel = false / true; if uppercase I can't access it, it has to be static but it errors out if I add static on public static bool ShowLabel;

Comment: @hypnocool Why you can;t access uppercase property? It's public, just use my model.